# How to do a subtask in python which involves putting a form on the web and receiving data from it

Tags: javascript, php, python, http, web

Basically my problem is the following:

In a python program I generate a set of documents.

These documents need to be put up on the web, where users label them. (this means that when the documents are put up on the web, they each have like a combo box by them and the user can select true or false. A labeled document is one for which the user has selected a label)

After a document is labeled, we want to receive the ID of the document and its label in the python application.

After enough labels are collected, we terminate the web page and the python program can proceed with execution.

The problem doesn't seem so hard, but I want your advice on how to solve it in an elegant way.

Thank you

Comment: take a look at [cgi](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html)